# Difference between potentially shippable product (PSP) and Minimal Marketable Feature (MMF)

Tags: agile, scrum

PSP is increment, i get in the end of sprint. Something, valuable for client.
MMF is not the same? I though, is valuable for client too...

Please, help me to understand difference between PSP and MMF

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potentially Shippable Product = The product is good enough that it *could* be shipped. It's up to the Product Owner if they do want to ship it.

Minimum Marketable Feature = A stated set of features that will *probably* form a release.

nb: The terms MMF (Minimum Marketable Feature) and MVP (Minimum Viable Product) are often used interchangeably.

Comment: so, the MMF is bigger, than PSP?

Comment: @zzfima Usually, yes. Though it is possible for a PSP to also be an MMF.

Comment: can you, please, redirect me to some source in internet so i can deeply understand it? Thanks

Comment: @zzfima For Minimum Viable Product, [Eric Ries wrote the book](http://theleanstartup.com/)  For Minimum Marketable Feature, try starting with [Roman Pichler] (http://www.romanpichler.com/blog/agile-product-innovation/the-minimal-marketable-product/) but you'll find lots of references via Google. Finally, for Potentially Shippable Product, read the [Scrum Guide] (http://www.scrumguides.org/)